# Mysql : How to find non duplicate rows with left join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, exists

I got a problem in Mysql sine a few days and i can't solve it (i'm pretty bad with DB) and I hope you can help me :)
I'm going to simplify the problem so you can see where I'm stuck !

I got two tables :

```
current_stock (article_id, ...)
stock_record (id, article_id)
```

Current_stock describes the actual stock and stock_record the articles which have already been inventoried.

The problem comes when I want to get the articles left to inventory (thoses in current_stock but not in stock_record), and when i got multiples sames articles_id

I tried :

```
SELECT * 
FROM current_stock 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM stock_record)
```

And others forms like :

```
SELECT *
FROM current_stock
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM stock_record) second
WHERE second.article_id IS NULL
```

BUT, when there a multiple lines with the same article_id in current_stock, AND there is one line with this article_id in stock_record, i'm not getting the good result !

For exemple:

```
current_stock (article_id)
8315
8315
8315

stock_record (id, article_id)
15, 8315
```

I want the result to have two rows with the article_id 8315 !

(Sorry for my bad english, hope you guys understand me !)

EDIT :

With theses forms i'm getting nothing in the result, because the "NOT EXISTS" or the "LEFT JOIN" is excluding ALL the lines from current_stock with this article_id.

I would like to exclude only the amount of lines in stock_record

For exemple :

I have 10 articles in my current_stock(with the article_id = 8315)
I have 3 articles already scanned in my stock_record(with the article_id = 8315)

I want the result to have 7 lines of this article_id.

Comment: What diffentiates the three records of `current_stock` having `article_id = 8315`? I mean, how can you tell the two are the good ones and the third is the bad one?

Comment: If you have multiple items on the current_stock , i think you need a line_item id (unique) in both tables to identify which item exists in the stock_record.

Comment: I dont need to tell wich one is the good one, I only need to return in the result the good amount of rows with this Id.
nrResult = nrCurrentStock - nrStockRecord 
For the same article_id

Comment: @DorianP. So you are only looking for a number ? , i mean not the whole row with that article_id ? , in your example , what you want is something like number 2 ? because that is the available count of that id in current_stock ?

Comment: Please check my answer. I think it does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to enumerate records. Then join on row number and ignore rows having a match in `stock_record`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         @rn1 := IF(@aid = article_id, @rn1 + 1,
                    IF(@aid := article_id, 1, 1)) AS rn1
  FROM current_stock 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0, @aid := 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY article_id) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT article_id, 
         @rn2 := IF(@aid = article_id, @rn2 + 1,
                    IF(@aid := article_id, 1, 1)) AS rn2
  FROM stock_record 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2 := 0, @aid := 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY article_id
) AS t2 ON t1.article_id = t2.article_id AND t1.rn1 = t2.rn2
WHERE t2.article_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're a GOD ! <3

Answer (score 1):

Your correct exists() query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM current_stock t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM stock_record s
                   where t.article_id = s.article_id)
```

The problem in your query, that you need to check if a **specific** id not exists in stock_record, and not if any id not exists there.

And your correct left join query:

```
SELECT *
FROM current_stock s
LEFT JOIN stock_record t on( t.article_id = s.article_id)
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

The problem with your left join query is that you didn't specify a relation condition (see the ON()) so, it didn't know which row to join to which row.

You can also use NOT IN like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM current_stock t
WHERE article_id NOT IN(SELECT article_id FROM stock_record)
```

Comment: Yes, in fact I did what you said, but the set of results are not what I expect. I need to "count" the occurences of an article_id.

Comment: I think this will give the same result with the query in OP, since you use the article_id.

Comment: @DorianP. what gave you a wrong result? those query are fine.. japongskie what do you mean?

Comment: I've also added a NOT IN solution

Comment: The result that i'm expecting is a set of rows containing n rows with this article_id whith:
n = number of rows of current stock for this article_id MINUS number of rows of stock_record with this article_id

IS it possible ?

Comment: So you want it to a specific ID? still didn't follow you.. what results are you currently getting and why are they wrong @DorianP.

Comment: @sagi Thanks for helping, Giorgos found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

try to group by current_stock

[This link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) will help you